# Prove that the Inverse Parametric equation is continuous.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Original question:

Show that a cylinder {$(x,y,z) \in  R^3 : x^2+y^2=1$} is a regular surface, and 
find parametrization whose coordinate neighborhoods cover it.

First of all, what do it mean to cover it?

Secondly I let $X = (cos(t),sin(t),z)$ on $R^2 \to R^3$   for my parameterization and it is obviously differentiable in the sense that its partial derivatives of any variables and degree exist. 
Second it's continuous since it's differentiable. X is 1-1 since z is 1-1. 
How do we show X is onto? Also is both t and z my 2 variables in $R^2$ that I am using?

Also how do I prove that $X^{-1}$ is also continuous?

Thirdly I have to show that for each point in a subset U of $R^2$ its differential is 1-1. The book says this is true if the Jacobian is non-zero.

Comment: Honestly, I've very lost, as you can tell.

Answer (score 0):

With your definition, $X$ is not itself 1-1 because $(t,z)$ and $(t+2\pi n,z)$ map to the same point on the cylinder. One has to restrict the $t$ to intervals somehow to avoid this, and include all the covered values, and this means there will be two (at least) parts or "charts" for the map.

Comment: Okay then $0 \le t \lt 2\pi$

Comment: Is $t \in [0,2\pi)$ = U?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But I think one other chart would be used here normally, such as $\pi \le t < 3\pi,$ in order that the points near $t=0$ are covered by only one map.

Comment: I think the text must be thinking of e.g. $U=(0,2\pi)\times \mathbb{R},$ in order to have a two dimensional part of space to map into the two dimensional cylinder. Then also $V=(\pi,3\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$ to complete the covering.

Comment: By 'chart' do you mean a region of a surface? Or maybe the intersection of the surface S with a neighborhood V of a point p on the surface X?

Comment: By "chart" I mean a map from part of a Euclidean space into a manifold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20941/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-adam-staples).